# Pylance autocompletion with subclasses

Tags: python, pylance

The problem is that in the following situation, autocompletion in the **SubFoo** class does not work in Pylance. Pylance only recognize the methods and attributes of the **Bar** class inside **SubFoo** class, but not the methods and attributes of the **SubBar** class. Am I doing the right thing?

```
class Bar:

    def method1(self):
        # do stuff


class SubBar(Bar):

   def method2(self):
       # do stuff


class Foo:

    def __init__(self, arg: Bar):
        self.attr: Bar = arg

    def do_a(self):
       self.attr.method1()


class SubFoo(Foo):

    def __init__(self, arg: SubBar):
        super().__init__(arg)
 
    def do_b(self):
       self.attr.method1() # Pylance's autocopmletion recognizes method1()
       self.attr.method2() # Pylance's autocopmletion doesn't recognize method2()
```

Comment: you're not setting self.atr anywhere..

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake(  self.attr is the same as self.atr

Comment: you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73544765/edit) your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared the type of `Foo.attr` to be `Bar`. The fact that it *happens* to be assigned a `SubBar` at some point is not the type checker's concern. If you want to statically know the type of the field based on the subclass, then `Foo` should be [generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic).

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

_T = TypeVar("_T", bound=Bar)

class Foo(Generic[_T]):

    def __init__(self, arg: _T):
        self.attr: _T = arg

    def do_a(self):
       self.attr.method1()


class SubFoo(Foo[SubBar]):

    def __init__(self, arg: SubBar):
        super().__init__(arg)
 
    def do_b(self):
       ...
```

Now subclasses of `Foo` are required to report *which* subclass of `Bar` they expect their constructor to receive, and that type information becomes available statically.

You'll also want to consider making that type variable [covariant](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance), if your use case supports it.

Comment: welp, looks like you beat me to it :-)